# about method predict in treebagger class in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

This method is working totally right in matlab. but, when I compiled it in a deployment (DLL files) the DLL can't call it. I think that because private function and these issues. Can any one help me?

I want to call it from the DLL or any equivalence method that will act the same. the tree is from type Compacttreebagger .. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the passed tree to the function predict is from class CompactTreeBagger then you should put this class definition to the help resources of your deployment tool otherwise you will get an error that the function predict is not defined to take integer parameter.